# How to create a select dropdown with an input for custom options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a select but have an input for 'custom' options within the drop down.  I've seen this around but I can't seem to find any explanation of how I can do this.  I suspect there is a jquery / javascript way to do this but can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean something like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop down with free input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180890/drop-down-with-free-input)

Comment: Actually, I have instead used a list that is converted to function like a dropdown which allows me to do all I need to.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a **ComboBox**.

Implementing such a tool will require some server-side code as well to persist any of the data entered.